# Cosa significa una "voce chioccia"?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Un matrimonio in provincia* della Marchesa Colombi (pseudonimo di Maria Antonietta Torriani) ho letto:

> Un giorno, che era a caccia coi soliti amici, avevano incontrato una vecchia; — e la descrisse, come le vecchie dei romanzi, curva, sdentata, e colla voce **chioccia**.

Nei dizionari ho trovato che una "chioccia" è una gallina quando cova le uova, ma in questa frase è chiaro che "chioccia" è un aggettivo. Mi sapreste spiegare cos'è una "voce chioccia"?

Comment: È una voce simile al verso della chioccia, che almeno io associo alle voci delle signore di una certa età. Si tratta di un'espressione risalente nientepopodimeno che alla Divina Commedia *Pape Satàn, pape Satàn aleppe!,/cominciò Pluto con la voce chioccia;* (Inferno, Canto VII vv.1-2)

Comment: Basta cercare la [voce giusta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chioccio/) (anche se credo di non averlo mai sentito usare al maschile).

Comment: @DaG Credo di non averlo mai sentito eccetto che riferito alla voce.

Comment: Giusto, @egreg, penso neanch'io, ma googlando per esempio “tono chioccio” qualcosa si trova.

Comment: Strega di Biancaneve come esempio? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGONYzIKjQI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come già detto, “chioccia” è qui il femminile dell'aggettivo “[chioccio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chioccio/)”, che detto di una voce o simili la caratterizza come rauca e stridula.

Per un italiano il riferimento più o meno obbligato (come ricorda Denis Nardin) sono i versi danteschi «“Pape, Satàn! pape, Satàn! aleppe!...” / cominciò Pluto con la voce chioccia» (If, VII, 1-2)».

Ne commenta l'*Enciclopedia Dantesca*: «la voce di Pluto è *chioccia*, ossia “rauca”, “aspra”, “di tono rauco e cupo” (Fallani); ma c'è nell'aggettivo una sfumatura che riguarda non soltanto il suono della voce, bensì anche l'*animus* del personaggio cui la voce appartiene; bene quindi il Sapegno: “rauca, rabbiosa” (“stridente e rotta”, Buti); il Sapegno continua: “È una spia dello stile ‘aspro’ a cui tutta la prima parte del canto s'intona, attraverso la ricerca di rime difficili, e quindi intensamente espressive, alla luce della tecnica e della poetica medievale (*-eppe*, *-occia*, *-abbia*, *-acca*, *-ipa*, *-iddi*, ecc.)”. / Lo stile ‘aspro’ cui allude il Sapegno riappare nel secondo dei due passi in cui troviamo l'aggettivo, *le rime aspre e chiocce* (“idest, rigidas”, Benvenuto) di *If* XXXII 1, dove lo stile comico è necessario per descrivere il *tristo buco*, cioè il nono cerchio dell'Inferno, che ospita i traditori».

Aggiungo però che, se l'aggettivo suona tuttora un po' “comico”, oggi raramente si porta dietro i connotati di asprezza e rabbia che caratterizzano il Pluto dantesco, e “con (la) voce chioccia” è rimasta un'espressione quasi fossilizzata, con pochissime varianti come “con tono chioccio” e simili.

Answer (score 2):

Per "voce chioccia" si intende una voce che suona roca o stridula come, appunto, il suono emesso da una gallina che cova.
Una tale voce risulta in genere sgradevole a chi l'ascolta.

L'aggettivo [chioccio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chioccio/) deriva dal verbo [chiocciare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chiocciare/).

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Francesco, e grazie della risposta!